# Is the velocity vector tangent to a dynamic path?

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Imagine a particle traveling along a curve (or surface). I cannot find anything on this topic that allows the curve (or surface) to change (or deform) as the particle moves. For a static curve, it is well known that the particle's velocity vector is tangent to the curve. (See, for example, [Is the tangential velocity the same as finding the tangent vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326287/is-the-tangential-velocity-the-same-as-finding-the-tangent-vector) ). But what happens if the curve along which the particle is moving, is itself changing as the particle moves? For example, imagine a particle moving along the circumference of an *expanding* circle. To simplify discussion, let's assume the particle moves at constant speed along the circumference, and that the radius of the circle increases at a constant rate (e.g., r(t) = a + c t). Is the particle's instantaneous velocity vector still tangent to the (expanding) circle? If not, how does the velocity vector relate to the equation of the circle?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The particle's path is never actually the circle. Its actual path looks more like a spiral. (Is the speed constant along that actual path, or is $r \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ constant, or some other restriction?)

Comment: aschepler, I edited the post to be more precise, in response to your questions.

Comment: It should be possible to do all calculations in the example of movement along the circle that expands at constant rate. Please do so.

Comment: Kurt G: I have been trying, and I do not know how to do it. That is why I posted the problem.

Comment: You should show in detail what you have tried. So far it is only a problem statement without visible own attempts.